# Slow Query when using class

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pdo

This is my View (show.php) where i have the courses (each course has 2-4 lessons)

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-mot">
    <?php
    if (count($corsi) > 0) {
        foreach ($corsi as $mm) {

            $lezioni=$mm->getLessons($mm->cou_id);
            echo "<tr class='odd gradeX'>";
            foreach ($lezioni as $lez) {
                $data=date('d-m-Y', (float)$lez->les_ts);
                $ora=date('H:i', (float)$lez->les_ts);
                echo "
                                                <td><span style=\"display: none;\">". $lez->les_ts."</span> 
                                                    <a href='?controller=courses&action=manageMoto&id=" . $mm->cou_id . "'>" . $data . "
                                                    <div>".$ora."</div>
                                                </td>";
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "<tr class='odd gradeX'><td>Nessun corso presente.</td><td></td><td><td></td><td></tr>";
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

This is the controller (courses.controller):

```
<?php
class CoursesController {

    public $tipo;
    public function show() {
        //I set the course type
        if (isset($_GET['type'])) {
            $this->tipo=$_GET['type'];
        }              
        $lezioni=getNumberLessonsByCourseType($this->getTipo());
        $corsi = Course::getCoursesbyType($this->getTipo());   
        require_once('views/courses/show.php');
    }
}
?>
```

And the courses_model.php

```
<?php
include_once("connection.php");
include_once("model.php");
include_once("lessons_model.php");

Class Course extends Model{
    public $cou_id;
    public $cou_type;
    public $cou_status;
    public $cou_fbid;

    public function __construct($cou_id=null, $cou_type=null, $cou_status=null, $cou_fbid=null)
    {
        $this->cou_id = $cou_id;
        $this->cou_type = $cou_type;
        $this->cou_status = $cou_status;
        $this->cou_fbid = $cou_fbid;
    }

    public static function getCoursesbyType($type) {
        $connection= new Database();
        $selectCou = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM courses WHERE cou_type = :type order by cou_id desc');          
        $selectCou->bindParam(':type', $type, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $selectCou->execute();

        $list = [];
        foreach($selectCou->fetchAll() as $corso) {
            $list[] = new Course($corso['cou_id'], $corso['cou_type'], $corso['cou_status'],$corso['cou_fbid']);
        }

        return $list;
        $connection=null;
    }

    public static function getLessons($id) {
        $connection= new Database();
        $id = intval($id);

        $selectLess = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM lessons WHERE les_course = :id');

        $selectLess->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $selectLess->execute();

        $list = [];
        foreach($selectLess->fetchAll() as $lezione) {
            $list[] = new Lesson($lezione['les_id'], $lezione['les_course'], $lezione['les_ts'],$lezione['les_number'],$lezione['les_instructor']);
        }
        return $list;
        $connection=null;
    }
}
```

And I have also lessons_model.php (for each course I have an array of Lessons)

```
Class Lesson extends Model{

public $les_id;
public $les_course;
public $les_ts;
public $les_number;
public $les_instructor;

public function __construct($les_id=null, $les_course=null, $les_ts=null, $les_number=null, $les_instructor=null)
{
$this->les_id = $les_id;
$this->les_course = $les_course;
$this->les_ts = $les_ts;
$this->les_number = $les_number;
$this->les_instructor = $les_instructor;
}
}
```

getNumberLessonsByCourseType is a simple function:

```
function getNumberLessonsByCourseType($course) {
    switch($course){
        case 'mot': $number=3; break;
        case 'mos': $number=3; break;
        case 'mop': $number=2; break;
        case 'sam': $number=2; break;
        case 'sen': $number=4; break;
    }


    return $number;

}
```

The problem is that when I call the controller (method show) I need almost 10 seconds to have all the courses and for each of them his lessons. It is too slow.
The query in workbench is not slow, and the courses are 700, so not many.

Comment: Btw, code after `return` will __never__ be executed.

Comment: wheres the code definition for `getNumberLessonsByCourseType `

Comment: Maybe im missing something but these $connection= new Database(); lines are buging me.
The getLessons() method is defined in the Course class as a static method but is called as non-static method : $mm->getLessons($mm->cou_id); 
Im not sure how this is supposed to react, but if it creates a new Database object on each iteration and if the Database class constructor opens a new sql connection, it means you end your loop with 700 hundreds opened connections. That would explain the slowness.
Just add a var_dump($connection) where you connect to mysql and let's see the result of it.

Comment: I tryied also with a singleton pattern on the database (so I will have only an instance) but is is still slow, nothing changed

Comment: I put the getNumberLessonsByCourseType function. It is a simple function, I don't think the problem is there:

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: You have 700 courses - And for each one you are running `$lezioni=$mm->getLessons($mm->cou_id);` where an SQL query is executed.
So if the query to get the lessons executes in 15 msec (which can be considered fast) 700 of those queries will take about 10 seconds.

What you can do is to fetch all lessons for all courses in one query and assign them to the courses in PHP.

```
Class Course extends Model{
    // ...

    public $lessons = [];

    // ...

    public static function getCoursesWithLessonsByType($type) {
        $connection = new Database();
        $selectCou = $connection->prepare('
            SELECT * 
            FROM courses
            WHERE cou_type = :type
            order by cou_id desc
        ');          
        $selectCou->bindParam(':type', $type, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $selectCou->execute();

        $list = [];
        foreach($selectCou->fetchAll() as $corso) {
            $list[$corso['cou_id']] = new Course(
                $corso['cou_id'],
                $corso['cou_type'],
                $corso['cou_status'],
                $corso['cou_fbid']
            );
        }

        $selectLess = $connection->prepare('
            SELECT l.*
            FROM lessons l
            JOIN courses c ON c.cou_id = l.les_course
            WHERE c.cou_type = :type'
        );
        $selectLess->bindParam(':type', $type, PDO::PARAM_INT);;
        $selectLess->execute();

        foreach($selectLess->fetchAll() as $lezione) {
            $list[$lezione['les_course']]->lessons[] = new Lesson(
                $lezione['les_id'],
                $lezione['les_course'],
                $lezione['les_ts'],
                $lezione['les_number'],
                $lezione['les_instructor']
            );
        }      

        return $list;
    }

    // ...
}
```

In your controller:

```
$corsi = Course::getCoursesWithLessonsByType($this->getTipo());
```

In your view:

```
$lezioni = $mm->lessons;
```

#### Notes

You shouldn't open and close a connection every time you want to run a query. At least use a singleton like:

```
$connection = Database::getInstance();
```

For best performance you should have the following indexes:

- `courses(cou_type, cou_id)` or just `courses(cou_type)` which is the same if `cou_id` is the primary key
- `lessons(les_course[, ...])` - It can be a composite index, but must begin with `les_course`

Comment: I have a problem in the Model, the variable $lessons[] cannot be recognized, because it is a static method. I tryied with self::$lessons but with this error (uniform variable syntax is available in php 7 only)

Comment: @m.Sarto `lessons` is a property of a `Course` object. You have to access it with `$courseObject->lessons`.

Comment: @m.Sarto I fixed my code. It should be `$list[$lezione['les_course']]->lessons[]` instead of `$list[$lezione['les_course']]->$lessons[]`.

Comment: Thank you, now it works but the execution time remains the same, and it is too much, not 10 seconds but 29 for only 155 courses. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: @m.Sarto Profile your code and locolize the slow part. If it's the query, the you are probably missing some indexes.